# how to specify set of files to be copied in lib while creating war

Tags: ant

This is my build target

```
   <target name="build-war" depends="build-java">        
     <war destfile="${dist.dir}/${std.war.file}" webxml="${resources.dir}/WEB-INF/web.xml">  
      <fileset dir="${jsp.dir}" />
       <lib dir="${lib.dir}"/>  
       <classes dir="${build.classes.dir}" />  
     </war>  
   </target>
```

Here for `<lib>` can i specify some how a fileset / pattern set ?

1. Basically i want to copy different
   jar from different places. (Not in
   one directlry)
2. And That fileset or patternset i want to be defined in another build file which actually imports this build file.

   ```
      <lib refid="${patternset.id}"/>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply define several `<lib>` elements:

```
<war destfile="myjar.jar">
    <lib dir="${dir1}" includes="*.jar"/>
    <lib dir="${dir2}" includes="*.jar"/>
</war>
```

Comment: Yes...But my issue is, this is a root build file. And the children will have list of files to be copied.

root-build.xml
<war destfile="myjar.jar">
// Need list of files to be copied into lib
</war>

child-build.xml
<import "root-build.xml">
//Contains a patternset or something that has list of files.

I considered alternative like pathTofileset and filese, but all of them need root directory.

Where as in my case, I have files from different directories. 

In essence, Is there a datastructure which can take list of files and i can refer to that in war target ?